# Making a bash script to build and run a C++ program

Tags: bash, scripts, c++

I'm trying to make a bash script to build and run a C++ program at once with one command, normally right now I have to do

```
g++ file.cc -o file
./file < input.in
```

I want to be able to do, say

```
brun file.cc < input.in
```

How can I do this? Right now I have something that can be run like

```
brun file.cc '< input.in'
```

Here's my current script

```
#!/bin/bash

CFILE=$1
OBJFILE="${CFILE%.*}"

g++ $CFILE -o $OBJFILE
echo  "Built file: $CFILE -> $OBJFILE"
chmod +x $OBJFILE

ARGS="${@##*.cc}"
./$OBJFILE""$ARGS
```

Which gets stuck at the last line, it just doesn't do anything then. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: This question is on wrong site, you need to go to https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be sufficient:

```
#!/bin/bash

CFILE=$1
OBJFILE="${CFILE%.*}"

g++ $CFILE -o $OBJFILE
echo  "Built file: $CFILE -> $OBJFILE"

./$OBJFILE
```

And you should be able to call it thus:

```
brun file.cc < input.in
```

This works because the input redirected to STDIN of the `brun` script is simply buffered, and that buffered input is then available to whichever sub-process reads it first - in this case your newly-built executable.

---

You might also consider using `make` to automate your build.  `make` is smart enough to do your build from default rules without the need for an explicit makefile.  So your build/run script could be as simple as:

```
#!/bin/bash

OBJFILE="${1%.*}"
make "$OBJFILE" && ./$OBJFILE
```

The `&&` here ensures that OBJFILE is only run if there were no build errors found by `make`.

Comment: `chmod +x $OBJFILE` isn't necessary. `g++` creates an executable file.

Comment: Actually, you can just tell `make` to run the file after building too. Something like: `%: %.c`, `g++ $^ -o $@`, `./$@`, and you call `make file`.

Comment: @muru Yes, that's another way, though it requires the use of a Makefile.  Personally, I like the simplicity of `make myprog && ./myprog`